# Efficient numpy broadcasting not found

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, array-broadcasting

It may be an easy problem but I could not find any practical solution. My code has following code segment involving 3 nested for loops. The target is to create a specialized intensity matrix for my algorithms for both `prediction` and `ground_truth` image matrix as follows:

```
    for i in range (batch):
      for j in range (img_width):
        for k in range (img_height):
            tensor=prediction[i][j][:]-prediction[i][k][:]
            extracted_intensity_pred[i][j][k]=torch.norm(tensor, 2)
            tensor=ground truth[i][j][:]-ground_truth[i][k][:]
            extracted_intensity_ground_truth[i][j][k]=torch.norm(tensor, 2)
```

This nested for loop structure is slowing the execution intensively. Is there any broadcasting implementation(in numpy or pytorch tensor based) that may be used?

Answer (score 1):

first lets clean up some notation; `[:]` does nothing

But first what's the dimensions, mostly 3d?

```
for i in range (batch):
      for j in range (img_width):
        for k in range (img_height):
            tensor = prediction[i,j,:] - prediction[i,k,:]
            # looks like a prediction[:,:,None]-prediction[:,None,:]; making 4d?
            extracted_intensity_pred[i,j,k] = torch.norm(tensor, 2)
            # what can torch.norm work with?
```

so maybe it's just

```
 tensor = prediction[:,:,None] - prediction(:,None,:]
 extracted_intensity_pred = torch.norm(tensor, ?)
```

Comment: Yes, its 3D Matrix

Comment: Your solution does not work. I restate the dimension of all the matrices in the problem. all vectors including 'prediction' and 'extracted_intensity_pred' is of dimensity [batch , img_width, img_height]